# How to download folder to a specific directory

Tags: python, selenium

```
# print links
x = '\n'.join(links)
print(x)
```

This is the output I have when I `print(x)`:

https://leidata.gleif.org/api/v1/concatenated-files/lei2/get/28683/zip

When I run `webbrowser.open(x)`, a zip file is automatically downloaded to the Downloads folder (doesn't open a web page).
Is there any way I can change the download to another directory?

Comment: Please share your full code and clearify the question

Comment: If you'd like to download a file to a specific location either set up the download folder of the selenium session or grab the url and make a get request and save the response body to the desired location. If you'd like to have more specific answer, update your question.